# Socket.io with AudioContext send and receive audio Errors on receiving

Tags: node.js, sockets, audio, socket.io, audiocontext

I am trying to build something, where a user can send audio instantly to many people using, socket.io, audioContext, js for the front-end and Node.js,socket.io for the server.

I can record the audio, send it to the server and send it back to other users, but I cannot play the data. I guess it must be a problem of how I send them or how I process the buffer that receives them.

I get the following error: **Update!**

<strike>The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.</strike>

**Audio is passed fine, the buffer is created with no errors but there is no sound feedback.**

The User presses record and it started recording/streaming with he following functions:

This is how it all starts:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true,video: false}, initializeRecorder, errorCallback);



function initializeRecorder(stream) {

  var bufferSize = 2048;
  audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  var recorder = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
  recorder.onaudioprocess = recorderProcess;
  source.connect(recorder);
  recorder.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  recording = true;
  initialized = true;
  play = false;
  stop = true;
}

function recorderProcess(e) {
          var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
          socket.emit('audio-blod-send', convertFloat32ToInt16(left));
       }

function convertFloat32ToInt16(buffer) {
     l = buffer.length;
     buf = new Int16Array(l);
     while (l--) {
       buf[l] = Math.min(1, buffer[l])*0x7FFF;
     }
     return buf.buffer;
   }
```

Then the server uses the socket to broadcast what the original sender send:

```
socket.on('audio-blod-send',function(data){
  socket.broadcast.to(roomName).emit('audio-blod-receive', data);
});
```

And then the data are played: **Update!**
I was using audioContext.decodeData which I found out that it is only used to read/decode audio from MP3 or WAV files not streaming. With the new code no errors appear however there is no Audio feedback.

```
    socket.on('audio-blod-receive',function(data) {
      playAudio(data);
    });

function playAudio(buffer)
  {
    var audioCtx;
    var started = false;
    if(!audioCtx) {
      audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    }

    source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    audioBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer( 1, 2048, audioCtx.sampleRate );
    audioBuffer.getChannelData( 0 ).set( buffer );
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect( audioCtx.destination );
    source.start(0);
    console.log(buffer);
  }
```

*P.S If anyone is interested further in what I am trying to do, feel free to contact me.*

Comment: Hi, have any progress with Audio feedback? I have same problem.

Comment: Hi @drakoumelitos did you ever get this working properly? We're trying to get audio streams working in a similar fashion but having problems getting the audio to play.

Comment: @AlanHollis no man, I gave up, sometimes it would work and I would hear static others hear nothing..

Comment: @drakoumelitos  did you get any success , please provide the link to your github repo _/\_ .

Comment: @SourabReddy I am on holidays at the moment, and I haven't updated the project. will let you know on the 6th or so .. sorry (made a note on my calendar)

Comment: @drakoumelitos ok I will mark a reminder for 6th then , I am planning to make a browser to browser audio caller and host that on a raspi , as we live in hostels connected by the same lan , this will serve as a free alternative to phone calls .

Comment: @SourabReddy I have sent you an email with the code.

Comment: Thanks @drakoumelitos I am highly obliged devrespect!

Comment: this is my mail sourab.reddy2k14@gmail.com, can you please resend , I did not get your original mail , my bad .